# How to fix ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
p = 'GEOM ((55.23 21.74, 55.26 21.74, 55.26 21.71829, 55.23 21.71, 55.23 21.74))'
```

I need to convert each coordinate into float number as follows:

```
arr = p.replace("GEOM ((", "").replace("))", "").split(",")
for i in arr:
  print(float(i.split(" ")[0]))
```

The problem is that the `float(...)` operation returns an error `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`.

Comment: Double check what `i` is and what `i.split(" ")[0]` returns. You're parsing the data incorrectly and getting what appears to be spaces.

Comment: You need to `float(i.strip().split(' ')[0])`

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code. This is a critical skill to learn as a beginning programmer.

Comment: @DavidZemens: What `.strip()` is doing?

Comment: Getting rid of the leading/trailing whitespace because the result of your split will give you (on the second iteration, for instance) `['', '55.26', '21.74']`, and it's failing to `float('')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you explicitly tell `split()` to use the space character, you will accidentally create splits with more than two elements and it will not be what you want. You can either call `split()` with no argument, or call `strip()` on the string before splitting it:

```
for i in arr:
    i.split()[0]
```

```
for i in arr:
    i.strip().split(" ")[0]
```

Both should work.

If you want to be super robust, you could use `strip()` with `partition()`:

```
for i in arr:
    i.strip().partition(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some sort of [Well-Known-Text (WKT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) string.
If that's the case you can use a library like [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.wkb.loads) to read the string directly into an easy to manipulate object.

However, it appears that `GEOM` isn't a valid WKT type.  If we assume it's a polygon, we can change GEOM to POLYGON and load it as a *wkt* directly to a Polygon object, with all sorts of helper methods available:

```
>>> from shapely import wkt
>>> g = 'GEOM ((55.23 21.74, 55.26 21.74, 55.26 21.71829, 55.23 21.71, 55.23 21.74))'
>>> p = g.replace('GEOM', 'POLYGON')
>>> poly = wkt.loads(p)
>>> list(poly.exterior.coords)
[(55.23, 21.74), (55.26, 21.74), (55.26, 21.71829), (55.23, 21.71), (55.23, 21.74)]
```